# "Error running '__rvm_make install'" when updating Ruby

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to update Ruby (it's 2.0.0p645 now) on OS X 10.11 El Capitan:

```
rvm install 2.2.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.11/x86_64/ruby-2.2.3.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more  information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/pashinsky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.3 - #downloading ruby-2.2.3, this may take a while depending on your connection...
    ...
ruby-2.2.3 - #extracting ruby-2.2.3 to /Users/pashinsky/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.3....
ruby-2.2.3 - #configuring......................................................-
ruby-2.2.3 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.2.3 - #compiling.........................................................
ruby-2.2.3 - #installing............
Error running '__rvm_make install',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/pashinsky/.rvm/log/1444763500_ruby-2.2.3/install.log
from /Users/pashinsky/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:42:in `fetcher'
from /Users/pashinsky/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:37:in `initialize'
from /Users/pashinsky/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:430:in `new'
from /Users/pashinsky/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:430:in `resolve_dependencies'
from /Users/pashinsky/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:373:in `install'
from /Users/pashinsky/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems.rb:558:in `install'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:722:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:721:in `each'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:721:in `block in <main>'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:757:in `call'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:757:in `block in <main>'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `each'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `<main>'
make: *** [do-install-nodoc] Error 1
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make install. Halting the installation.
```

Googling it for a couple of hours now with no luck. Neither `rvm get head` nor `rvm get master` doesn't help. Actually, nothing of all that I've found (those were solutions for slightly different errors though) did help.

I also tried `rvm all do gem errors`, but the output gives me no clue:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 30 (Psych::SyntaxError)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:319:in `load_file'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:192:in `initialize'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `new'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:66:in `do_configuration'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:46:in `run'
from /usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Comment: did you try `rvm get master` then
`rvm reinstall 2.2.3`

Comment: @Cyzanfar yes I did, ended up with exact same error (added it to the question, thanks)

Comment: mee too, i have this error when i was trying to update to 2.2.4 any solutions?

Comment: Hey @Ccr, in my case the problem was just a gemfile located at Users/%username%/, probably from some old project/ruby tutorial. I just deleted it and it worked! (I'm not 100% sure that it was gemfile, though... If I'm wrong, just try and look for some ruby-related documents in your user directory)